# Get label from input class

Tags: css, class, input, label

I have to insert "*" to the label only if input is required.

There is a way to get the label of the input tag from the class .notEmpty?

```html
<label for="foo">Foo</label>
<input class="notEmpty" id="foo">
```

Comment: Not possible with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the field required and then use the input:valid selector to show the star when the field is empty.

Markup:

```
<label for="foo">Foo</label>
<input class="text" id="foo" required="required">
<span class="star" style="visibility: visible;">*</span>
```

CSS:

```
.text:valid + .star { visibility: hidden!important; }
```

See a working CodePen Here: https://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/aWpqqj

Answer (score 0):

You can try a little hack something like this :

```css
label{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.notEmpty + label::after{
  content: '*';
}
```

```html
<input class="notEmpty" id="foo">
<label for="foo">Foo</label>
```